# Is there a scripting IDE of choice for VBscript / powershell?

Tags: scripting

We can't really do our job correctly without scripting, and sometime these scripts can be difficult to create / debug with only text editors

I'm currently using [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as text editors and scripting platform (syntax highlighting is almost mandatory), but I was wondering if there was a more advanced scripting environment, an IDE of some sort, for VBscript and Powershell mostly ? (like always, free is better, but if the tool is really good I'm not against paying for it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Windows PowerShell ISE](https://web.archive.org/web/20160419085736/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) in PowerShell 2.0 ([part](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-v2-is-available/) of [Windows Management Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20110704032306/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)).

Comment: The Powershell ISE is great for Powershell, but can't really be used for VBscript as well :(